# How to clear naviagation history and exit from phonegap application?

Tags: android, windows-phone-7, cordova, phonegap-build

user navigates in following way :-

landing screen --> screen 1 ---> screen 2

screen 2 on press of home goes to landing screen.

so now **when the user is in landing screen(home screen) i want to exit from the application** (even if some navigation history is available).

**this is what i have used :-**

```
var app = {
    initialize: function () {
        this.bind();
    },
 bind: function () {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.deviceready, false);

        $(window).bind('orientationchange', this.orientationchange);
    },
    deviceready: function () {

        document.addEventListener("backbutton", function (e) {
           if ($.mobile.activePage.is('#landingscreen')) {
                e.preventDefault();
                navigator.app.exitApp();
            }
           else {
                navigator.app.backHistory()
            }
        }, false);
....
}
};
```

by using the above code i want to able to exit the app if i am in home screen , in spite of that backbutton in all screens are not working, i don't know why ??

1)how can i achieve when the user is in landing screen(home screen) i want to exit from the application ??

2) how can i achieve the same even in windows phone phonegap app , is there any other way specially in which i should handle for windows phone phonegap app??

Please let me know

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

Just do one thing take a `Boolean` variable `isHomeScreen` and make it `true` when you are at home screen otherwise make it `false` and when you press `back button` just check that variable as

```
if(isHomeScreen)
    navigator.app.exitApp();
else
    // What you want
```

Comment: what do you mean by navigator here?

Comment: navigator.app does not exist in windows phone phonegap